# Looping through nested laravel collections

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pull all unapproved comments from all posts. I'm getting all posts, looping through them and getting their comments. This leaves me with a nested collection / array. I'm unsure how to then loop through the nested levels to extract all comments. What I've tried so far is:

CommentsController:

```
    $posts = Post::all();
    $unapprovedcomments = collect([]);
    foreach($posts as $post){
      $unapprovedcomments->push($post->comments()->get());
    }

    dd($unapprovedcomments);
    return view('commentqueue')->with('unapprovedcomments',$unapprovedcomments);
```

commentqueue.blade.php:

```
@foreach($unapprovedcomments->map->Comment as $unapprovedcomment)

    <p>{{$unapprovedcomment->comment}}</p>

@endforeach
```

The dd output of $unapprovedcomments looks like this: (cropped)

[image]

The error I'm receiving at the moment is:

```
Property [Comment] does not exist on this collection instance
```

If I don't loop through all the posts and instead just pull the comments from one post, I can get the comments in the blade using:

```
@foreach($unapprovecomments as $unapprovedcomment)
    {{$unapprovedcomment->comment}}
@endforeach
```

How can I pull out all the comments? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$posts = Post::all();
$unapprovedcomments = $posts->pluck('comments')->collapse();
```

For better performance you should use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$posts = Post::all()->load('comments');
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I forgot about pluck. This is working and seems to be clean. Do you think doing "Post:all();" could be optimized at all? It doesn't seem necessary to grab all columns from all posts. I'm not familiar with eager loading so I'll read up on it. I'm assuming your recommendation here preloads the related comments.

Comment: Just a note, that's not [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) (who load all the relationships of the records), that is [Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) that loads the relationships of just the returned items of the previous query.

Comment: I see your point but `Post::all()->load('comments')` does exactly the same as `Post::with('comments')->get()`. I just wanted it to be very similar to the original code.